# Why the words "threatened with eviction" are added to this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/synopsis)

> Vito earns the respect of the neighborhood and begins to intercede in
>   local disputes, operating out of the storefront of his Genco Pura
>   Olive Oil Company (named after his friend Genco Abbandando) which he
>   manages as well as give out "favors" to others in the community **such
>   as a local young woman threatened with eviction**

Actually **such as a local young woman.** is enough to end the sentence but extra words are added.

Why the words "**threatened with eviction**" are added to this sentence?

Comment: This is a reduced relative clause: here is the un-reduced version.  "...such as a local young woman [who has been] threatened with eviction". It is not at all clearly written: is the young woman one of the 'favors', or a member of the community?

Comment: What makes you think they are extra words?  They seem Integral to the meaning of the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

*Threatened with eviction* gives us more information about the woman:

> such as a local young woman **who is** threatened with eviction

The *who is* has been omitted. So not only does Vito intercede in local disputes but he helps out community members too, like a local young woman who is threatened with eviction.